# Green_Shoes fails to build native gem extension

Tags: ruby, shoes

I'm trying to install green_shoes on Windows 8.1.  I have ruby 2.0.0p451 and gem version 2.0.14 on a 64-bit OS.  I also installed the ruby-gtk2 package recommended on the green_shoes page.  Any idea what's up?

```
C:\>gem install green_shoes
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing green_shoes:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for --enable-debug-build option... no
checking for -Wall option to compiler... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
        --enable-debug-build
        --disable-debug-build
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to ge
nerate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `block in try_compile'

        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:502:in `with_werror'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `try_compile'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/glib2-2.2.3/lib/mkmf-gnome2
.rb:58:in `block in try_compiler_option'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:895:in `block in checking_for
'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block (2 levels) in p
ostpone'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `postpone'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:894:in `checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/glib2-2.2.3/lib/mkmf-gnome2
.rb:57:in `try_compiler_option'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/glib2-2.2.3/lib/mkmf-gnome2
.rb:67:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:5
5:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:5
5:in `require'
        from extconf.rb:15:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/glib2
-2.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/glib2-2.2.3/ext/glib2/
gem_make.out
```

Comment: The error mentions `mkmf.log`, have you looked at this file? Could you please update your question with the contents of that file?

Comment: Any idea which mkmf.log I need to look at? There are a few, but none for green_shoes because the gem fails to install

Comment: I think it has something to do with glib2 not being properly installed, but the same 'failed to build native extension' error happens when I try to install that.  Running 'gem list' doesn't show glib2, which, I think, is a problem.

Comment: Do you have the Ruby DevKit installed? It should allow you to compile gems for your system if you're running Windows anything. Just make sure you get the right version of the DevKit for your version of Ruby, that can be a bit confusing.  http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/

Comment: I had DevKit installed, but I wasn't sure if it was properly configured so I deleted the DevKit folder and tried to reinstall.  After initializing, I ran 'ruby dk.rb install' and got the following message: "C:\Ruby200-x64>ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Skipping existing gem override for 'C:/Ruby200-x64'
[WARN] Skipping existing DevKit helper library for 'C:/Ruby200-x64'